# Pipe with additional Arguments

Tags: julia

I read in several places that pipes in Julia only work with functions that take only one argument. This is not true, since I can do the following:

```
function power(a, b = 2) a^b end
3 |> power
> 9
```

and it works fine.

However, I but can't completely get my head around the pipe. E.g. why is this not working?? :

```
3 |> power()
> MethodError: no method matching power()
```

What I would actually like to do is using a pipe and define additional arguments, e.g. keyword arguments so that it is actually clear which argument to pass when piping (namely the only positional one):

```
function power(a; b = 2) a^b end
3 |> power(b = 3)
```

Is there any way to do something like this?

---

I know I could do a work-around with the `Pipe` package, but to honest it feels kind of clunky to write `@pipe` at the start of half of the lines.

In `R` the `magritrr` package has convincing logic (in my opinion): it passes what's left of the pipe by default **as the first** argument to the function on the right - I'm looking for something similar.

Comment: Unrelated, but for such short function definitions you can use `power(a, b = 2) = a^b` instead of `function power(a, b = 2) a^b end`

Answer (score 4):

`power` as defined in the first snippet has two methods. One with one argument, one with two.  So the point about `|>` working only with one-argument methods still holds.

The kind of thing you want to do is called "partial application", and very common in functional languages.  You can always write

```
3 |> (a -> power(a, 3))
```

but that gets clunky quickly.  Other language have syntax like `power(%1, 3)` to denote that lambda.  There's [discussion](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/24990) to add something similar to Julia, but it's difficult to get right.  `Pipe` is exactly the macro-based fix for it.

If you have control over the defined method, you can also implement methods with an interface that return partially applied versions as you like -- many predicates in Base do this already, e.g., `==(1)`.  There's also the option of `Base.Fix2(power, 3)`, but that's not really an improvement, if you ask me (apart from maybe being nicer to the compiler).

And note that `magrittr`s pipes are also ["macro"-based](https://github.com/tidyverse/magrittr/blob/master/R/pipe.R).  The difference is that argument passing in R is way more complicated, and you can't see from outside whether an argument is used as a value or as an expression (essentially, R passes a thunk containing the expression and a pointer to the parent environment, and automatically evaluates and caches it if you use it as a value; see [`substitute`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/substitute))